# Deploy Maven RESTful webservice project with Glassfish to Ubuntu server

Tags: web-services, maven, ubuntu, jar, glassfish

First of all, I successfully created a RESTful webservice as Maven project. When I browse to http://localhost:8080/JsonService/vehiclegroups I receive a list with vehiclegroups. This is working perfectly when I run it in Netbeans.

Now I have the following question: **What are the steps to deploy my .jar to an ubuntu server?**

So I already created a jar with dependencies [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven). I defined a main class but this one is empty because all my code is inside the methods that are called when visiting a specific path.

When I run my .jar file, it only executes the code inside the main class and than it stops. How do I make sure it runs like inside Netbeans and receive data when browsing to the urls?

Do I have to install a Glassfish server on the Ubuntu and then run the jar? I want the program to keep running and answer all the path requests.

Thanks!

Comment: I got this so far: compile a .war file instead of a jar file. Install glashfish. Start glashfish and browse to :4848. Go to applications. Add the .war file and launch. Still got some issues with my dependencies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working! Install the Glassfish on the Ubuntu and browse to the admin panel. Go to applications > deploy > add the .war file.

You have to put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar inside the global lib folder of Glassfish to avoid errors.

Everything works fine after that.

Cheers!